# Visual C++ for Python failed with exit status 2

Tags: python-2.7, window

```
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_user\ssdeep\.eggs\cff
i-1.8.2-py2.7-win32.egg\cffi\ffiplatform.py", line 65, in _build
    raise VerificationError('%s: %s' % (e.__class__.__name__, e))

cffi.ffiplatform.VerificationError: CompileError: command 'C:\\Users\\user\\
AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin
\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

---

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\

---

I keep getting this error. I have tried multiple other solutions on here but no luck. Am I missing something. Thanks

Comment: What is the module that you are trying to install through pip?

Answer (score 3):

A crude method worked for me. Perhaps someone with knowledge can optimize the answer:

1. Read the following article [Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/)
2. Mine is Python 2.7. I followed the article and installed the Visual
   C++ compiler for python 2.7. [Install
   Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)
3. This installs a folder in your "%AppData%\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft".
4. I copied the contents of

   - "...\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\include"to the "C:\Python27\include"
   - "...\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\lib"to "C:\Python27\libs"
   - "...\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\WinSDK\Include" to "C:\Python27\include"
   - "...\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\WinSDK\lib" to "C:\Python27\libs"
5. I edited path in environmental variables to include these two directories ("C:\Python27\include" and "C:\Python27\libs". I think this step is not essential).
6. Edit the "msvc9compiler.py" in the directory "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils"

   - Line # ~270 hard coded link to "vcvarsall.bat" "%appdata%..\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\vcvarsall.bat"
   - Line # ~394 `os.environ['include'] = "C:\\Python27\\include"`
   - Line # ~396 `os.environ['lib'] = "C:\\Python27\\libs"`
   - Line # ~402 hard coded the link to `self.cc = "...\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe"` (caution: it is \Bin and not \bin.)
   - Line # ~403 Similar to above hard coded the link to self.linker.

Doing the above steps worked for me.

Comment: Step 4) I edited path in environmental variables to include these directories.
 
Step 5) Edit the msvc9compiler.py in the directory C:\Python27\Lib\distutils

Line # ~270 hard coded link to vcvarsall.bat "%appdata%\..\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\vcvarsall.bat"

Line # ~394 os.environ['include'] = "C:\Python27\include"

Line # ~396 os.environ['lib'] = "C:\\Python27\\libs"

Line # ~402 hard coded the link to self.cc = "...\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe" (caution: it is \Bin and not \bin.)

Line # ~403 hard coded the link to self.linker.

Doing the above steps worked for me.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to apply your solution but I stopped in step 6. can you please explain more about the changes in Line 270? I could not found the exact location to update the path.

Comment: To Sakurami, I just saw your message. Have you found the solution? If not, the line # 270 is expecting path for vcvarsall.bat. Instead, I hardcoded the path. If this explanation doesn't help, post the particular lines in your file.