# Unable to pip install cloudstorage module

Tags: python-2.7, sdk, pip, windows-10, google-cloud-storage

Hello beautiful people of the internet!

I'm having issue trying to:

```
pip intall --upgrade cloudstorage
```

under my local env using the basic windows CMD with google cloud SDK installed.

I'm on a Win10 with python 2.7.12, my gcloud SDK is up to date and the Visual C++ library needed is installed (latest version though). Still it raises this error when trying to install the module :

```
    [...]  
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcbuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_lib.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_lib.obj
    _lib.c
    build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_lib.c(504) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/xattr.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\user_name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\user_name\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-ekfv8g\\xattr\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-_ejcqu\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --home=c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\temp\pip-target-ndt9sh" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-ekfv8g\xattr\
```

I've also tried to run the installation under Debian WSL without success...
Also 'setuptools' is up to date.

Any clue, any one ?

**Edit:
Corrected with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358876/visual-c-for-python-failed-with-exit-status-2#answer-40399816). Getting a new error :**

```
[...]
MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR90.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\user_name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1112

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\user_name\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-8hhqj3\\netifaces\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\temp\pip-record-nmoe3e\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --home=c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\temp\pip-target-gb8zwx" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\user_name\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-8hhqj3\netifaces\
```

Answer (score 0):

**Corrected with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358876/visual-c-for-python-failed-with-exit-status-2#answer-40399816).**

Getting a new error though (cf: [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524725/unable-to-pip-install-cloudstorage-module)) - still interested in anyone finding a solution to this second one.